# Arch linux set up wifi issue

Tags: wifi, authentication

I've just finished setting up arch linux and am trying to configure wifi (wired internet works ok I checked).

As for wireless I have this issue: I try to connect to wireless router with `iw dev wlp1s0 connect talktalkodc61 key d:2: "my key"` - which I take it is the password that came with the router.

The issue is that I think the combination of letters and numbers needs to be converted to a hexadecimal key.....the error message I get states:

> "key must be [d:] index:data where
>   "d:" means default (transmit) key
>   "index:" is a single digit (0-3)
>   "data" must be 5 or 13 ASCII chars
>   or 10 or 26 hex digits
>
> for example d:2:6162636465 is the same as d:2:abcde..." 
>   etc etc.

The issue is that the passphrase I have that came with the router is alphanumerical. Does anyone know how to convert it to a format (PSK, TKIP etc) that would work for my situation?

Answer (score 3):

Verify what protocol your access point is using with `iwlist wlp1s0 scan` and looking for your access point's listing.

According to the Arch Linux [wiki entry on configuring wireless connections](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#iw) your syntax is for WEP. WEP is rarely used and most likely your router is using WPA2 and you'll need to configure it according to the [WPA2 section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#WPA2_Enterprise).

My suggestion is to use either [wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Advanced_usage) or [network manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager)